# Does a subclass inherit the protocols of its parent class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, protocols

Suppose I have a parent class that implements a protocol:

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController<GamePrizeDelegate> {
  ...
}
```

And then I make subclasses of it:

```
@interface TennisViewController : GameViewController {
  ...
}

@interface SoccerViewController : GameViewController {
  ...
}
```

Do I have to include the `GamePrizeDelegate` also in the subclasses? Are the protocols inherited as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Referring to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html): Your subclass does inherit the adoption of the protocol, so you don't have to adopt it again.

> [**Conforming to a Protocol**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html)
>
> A class is said to conform to a formal
> protocol if it adopts the protocol or
> **inherits from another class that
> adopts it**. An instance of a class is
> said to conform to the same set of
> protocols its class conforms to.